# /node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-7.6/fibers.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, fibers

I have an issue with starting my meteor bundle created with demeteorizer. When I am trying to start bundle I have error shown below.

NodeV: 0.10.40, fibersV: 1.0.1

I tried to `npm uninstall` fibers and `npm install` them again.

This is my error:

> /home/light-tech/Documents/demetorized-welcome-bar/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:13
>     throw new Error('`'+ modPath+ '.node` is missing. Try reinstalling
>   `node-fibers`?');     ^
>
> Error:
>   `/home/light-tech/Documents/demetorized-welcome-bar/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-7.6/fibers.node`
>   is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`?
>       at Object. (/home/light-tech/Documents/demetorized-welcome-bar/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:13:8)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
>       at Object. (/home/light-tech/Documents/demetorized-welcome-bar/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:1:13)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm
>   ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start: `node ../../main`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the
>   meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/light-tech/.npm/_logs/2019-11-08T12_34_41_274Z-debug.log

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm i <modulename> -g`

Note:
The -g will try to install the module globally, its recommended if you're trying to install an npm module that works as a CLI

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what demeteorizer does to the bundle, but in a normal meteor bundle there is README that instructs you to run:

```
(cd programs/server && npm install)
```

in your unpacked `bundle` folder. I suspect you didn't do this yet.